# Add every 3rd column of different files into one file

Tags: bash, awk, paste

I'm new to awk, so I hope someone could help

I have 55 text files (in TAB and have similar naming ending with .txt), all files contain exactly 55 rows and 4 columns. No row or column is missing. The only differences are the values within the file. They look similar like thes below (only containing 4 rows now and 3 files)

```
Row1    355 389 623
Row2    58  906 1373
Row3    338 3   30
Row4    2   976 0
```

```
Row1    543 31  6642
Row2    0   0   453
Row3    45  5   42
Row4    425 12  8
```

```
Row1    452 6   352
Row2    765 21  54
Row3    0   45  999
Row4    451 765 3
```

I would like to add the first column once (the names), and then every 3rd column from all files into one. *edit: and if possible the file name* The output should look like this:

```
        1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
Row1    389 31  6
Row2    905 0   21
Row3    3   5   45
Row4    976 12  765
```

I tried this code

```
paste * | awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1; next} {print a[FNR],$3}' *.txt > output.txt | column -t
```

However, it only adds values of the first 2 files. Values from other files were not present. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: What separator is used in your input files? Is it a _TAB_?

Comment: Yes, the files are TAB files!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (e.g. 3 files of 4 lines and 4 cols each) and the expected output given that input so it clearly demonstrates your requirements and gives us something we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I changed it. The files have similar namings but all are listed into one folder. Thus something like *.txt should be fine I guess? All files have exactly the same row and column numbers, only the values within differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- input/output field delimiter is `<TAB>`
- all input files contain the same number of rows
- all rows have at least 3 columns
- no need to sort the input files (ie, `Row1` is always in row #1, `Row2` is always in row #2, etc)
- `*.txt` will expand to a list of files in the desired order (eg, `1.txt1`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, etc); otherwise OP may need to pre-sort the file names before feeding them to the proposed solution

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="\t" }                           # input/output field delimiter is <TAB>

FNR==1  { lines[0]=lines[0] OFS FILENAME }        # append filename to "header" record

FNR==NR { lines[FNR]=$1 }                         # save the "RowN" string

        { lines[FNR]=lines[FNR] OFS $3 }          # append field #3 to the line

END     { for (i=0;i<=FNR;i++)                    # loop through the line numbers ...
              print lines[i]                      # printing each line to stdout
        }
' *.txt
```

Assuming the 3 sample input files are named `{1..3}.txt` this `awk` script generates:

```
        1.txt   2.txt   3.txt
Row1    389     31      6
Row2    906     0       21
Row3    3       5       45
Row4    976     12      765
```

Comment: Also, thank you for the explanations at every line. It helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

You could try this awk:

```
awk -F '\t' '
FNR==NR {table[FNR] = $1}
{table[FNR] = table[FNR] "\t" $3}

END {
    for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) {
        print table[i]
    }
}' *
```

The last (55th) value of FNR is used to print the array, so if the files don't all have the same number of lines, you will need to address that.

If you want to use `paste`, maybe something like this:

```
paste * |
awk '
{
    printf "%s", $1
    for (i=3; i<55*4; i+=4) {
        printf "\t%s", $i
    }
    printf "\n"
}'
```

`55*4` is number of files times number of columns. Hard coded. There are various methods of counting these if necessary.

Comment: `print ""` is better than `printf "\n"` because it just uses whatever value `ORS` has instead of hard-coding the string that you hope `ORS` is set to (`"\n"`). Also, instead of `55*4`, just use `NF`.